# Make migrations several files django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have django project with the next structure:

```
[projectname]/
├── core/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── custom_user/
│   ├── ...#some files 
│   └── models/
│       ├── user.py
│       └── tags.py
│ 
└── manage.py
```

How I can to run command makemigrations for several files (for user.py and for tags.py), now I'm trying to implement it by command `./manage.py makemigrations custom_user`, but I'm getting the next info `No changes detected in app 'custom_user'.`, I've defined the app in settings.py file in installed_apps as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'custom_user.apps.CustomUserConfig'
]
```

and in apps.py file too as:

```
class CustomUserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'custom_user'
```

Nevertheless if I add my models to usual `models.py` file everything works.

Comment: Maybe `__init__` file is missing?

Comment: No, doesn't help(

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I added `__init__.py` into the 'models' folder and included into the `__init__.py` module the following sample code:

```
from .<module name> import <class name>, <class name>

__all__ = [
    '<class name>',
    '<class name>'
    ]
```

My project structure was identical to Konstantin's project.

Answer (score 0):

In your app folder create a folder named migrations and inside it create the
`__init__.py` file

```
[app_folder]
  --migrations/
    --__init__.py
  --views.py
  --forms.py
  # others
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is adding to `__init__.py` file the necessary imports, here it is `from .user import *` and `from .tags import *`